# managed c++ code doesn't find function implementation

Tags: c++, linker-errors, managed-c++

I have 3 files:

1. main ".h" file - contains implementation of a simple WinForm (managed c++)
2. fold/file.h
3. fold/file.cpp

(file.h and file.cpp are not represent a class)

I have a function "func()" which its declaration is in fold/file.h, and its implementation is in fold/file.cpp.

There is include "fold/file.h" in main.h

When I call **func()** from main.h I get errors of: "Unresolved token" and "Unresolved external error". when I put the implementation of "func()" in  fold/file.h there is no error.

What is the problem?

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a linker error rather than a compiler error. Are you linking all your object files? Also, didn't "Managed C++" go to sleep with the fishes in 2003?

Comment: Would you post your code here? I believe it will explain better

Comment: @Kerrek: I was confused by your managed C++ comment, so I looked it up.  It appears "Managed C++" is deprecated, but "C++/CLI" isn't.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: @Merlyn: Those two are entirely different languages. Well, one is a language, the other is an abomination. The OP is encouraged to double-check the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I put the implementation of "func()" in fold/file.h there is no error.

Are you compiling all the source files ? I suspect you are not because when you bring the definitions to the header file and include it in the main source file, pre-processor actually copies it to the main source file. So, while compiling and linking the main translation unit, compiler and linker can see both the declarations and the definitions respectively.

Comment: I build the project and run it in visual studio 2010, so I don't think the problem is in the compiling

Comment: @DudiD - The error you get is a linker error. Not a compiler error. Linker is unable to find the definition for `func()`.

Comment: How can I fixt the linking problem? (in visual studio 2010)